# UNOCONV and LibreOffice

Tags: package-management, libreoffice

I have installed unoconv in my ubuntu with LibreOffice.
But I need to know what are the parts of LibreOffice I really need to install. Because I do not want to install LibreOffice whole.

This Unoconv, will work within a server. converting files from RTF to HTML and HTML to RTF and some files in DOC format

What packages will I need to install from LibreOffice?

Comment: Unoconv has python, and python-uno (with **libreoffice-core**) as a dependency. See my updated answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24096/handle-doc-docx-templates-on-a-headless-server-to-produce-pdfs-preferably-withou

Comment: Wow, I'll test some things i've got in your post, and then i'll post here any news. Very thanks!

Comment: @Takkat I recommend turning that into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Unoconv** will depend on the core library from libreoffice for conversion of different documents but we do not have to install all of the libreoffice package.

By running `apt-cache depends unoconv` we can see the following dependencies:

```
unoconv
  Depends: python
  Depends: python-uno
```

We will also need **python-uno** with the following dependencies:

```
python-uno
  Depends: libreoffice-core
  Depends: python2.7
  Depends: python
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libgcc1
  Depends: libpython2.7
  Depends: libstdc++6
  Depends: uno-libs3
  Depends: ure
```

Thus in addition to Python and C-libraries the following additional packages from the libreoffice suite (installed size on amd64 in brackets) are needed:

- **libreoffice-core** (117,412.0 kB)
- **uno-libs3** (1,796.0 kB)
- **ure** (6,775.0 kB)

Hence in terms of size roughly half of the libreoffice package will be installed with unovonv.

Comment: I'll try to do that today. then tell you what happened.

Comment: I installed "unoconv", but because of other things I could not test.
I will test then say what happened.

Comment: Works fine, I get promoted.